# I am trying to load a pdf file, simultaneously the other pdf file loads too but the app crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load a pdf file but i am getting an error due to the already existing PDF file.

```
private PDFView pdfView;
pdfView = (PDFView) aboutus_layout.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
pdfView.fromFile(file).onLoad(this).on‌​PageChange(this).load();
@Override 
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 
@Override 
public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
if (isAdded()) {
 if (pd.isShowing()) {
 pd.dismiss();
 Log.e("load complete", "load Complete"); 
 }
}
}
```

This is the stack Trace:

```
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944): java.lang.RuntimeException: error loading page
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfPage.open(Native Method)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfPage.createPage(PdfPage.java:55)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfDocument.getPage(PdfDocument.java:18)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at org.vudroid.core.DecodeServiceBase.getPage(DecodeServiceBase.java:175)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at org.vudroid.core.DecodeServiceBase.getPageWidth(DecodeServiceBase.java:214)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView.loadComplete(PDFView.java:635)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DecodingAsyncTask.java:55)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DecodingAsyncTask.java:1)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-21 09:51:01.619: E/AndroidRuntime(5944):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Include some of your code also.

Comment: private PDFView pdfView;pdfView = (PDFView) aboutus_layout.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);pdfView.fromFile(file).onLoad(this).onPageChange(this).load();@Override
 public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if (isAdded()) {
   if (pd.isShowing()) {
    pd.dismiss();
    Log.e("load complete", "load Complete");
   }

  }
 }